# Jetty Server automatically shuts down

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to start jetty from command-line, it takes some time to start after which it shows "Starting Jetty: Already Running 2645!". But after 2-3 minutes, when I again check, I see that the jetty server has shut down on it's own which I confirm by again using the start command which shows "Starting Jetty: ok Fri Apr 15 ". Also, in the mean-while I am unable to access the jetty from browser. This is happenning since the last 4-5 hours, before which it was running smoothly.

I am using OS linux, Java version 1.8, jetty version 9.2.14

Comment: "Starting Jetty: Already Running 2645!". suggests a Jetty process is already running in some fashion (possibly broken though) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat to check if jetty process is already running. If it is running then check if any bash script starts it automatically. Use sudo netstat -tnp to check the process name along with the port that connection is using.